# Erlang ssl non-blocking parallel acceptors

Tags: ssl, erlang

I have built a very naive parallel ssl acceptor.

```
-module(multiserver).
-export([start/0,client/1]).

%% This is a dummy SSL Erlang server/client example

start() ->
    spawn_link(fun() -> init([]) end).

init([]) ->
    ssl:start(),
    {ok, ListenSocket} = ssl:listen(9990, [{certfile, "cert.pem"}, {keyfile, "privkey.pem"} ,{reuseaddr, true},{active, true}, binary]),
    Pid = self(),
    spawn_link(fun() -> listener(ListenSocket, Pid, 1) end),
    spawn_link(fun() -> listener(ListenSocket, Pid, 2) end),

    loop().

loop() ->
    receive 
        {new, _Pid} ->
            %% Do stuff here
            loop()
    end.

listener(ListenSocket, Pid, Num) ->
    {ok, ClientSocket} = ssl:transport_accept(ListenSocket),
    ok = ssl:ssl_accept(ClientSocket),
    io:format("listener ~p accepted ~n", [Num]),

    ok = ssl:send(ClientSocket, "server"),
    io:format("listener ~p  sent~n", [Num]),

    receive
        X -> io:format("listener ~p: ~p ~n", [Num, X])
    after 5000 ->
            io:format("listener ~p timeout ~n", [Num]),
            timeout
    end,
    ssl:close(ClientSocket),

    listener(ListenSocket, Pid, Num).

client(Message) ->
    ssl:start(),
    {ok, Socket} = ssl:connect("localhost", 9990,  [binary, {active,true}], infinity),

    receive
        X -> io:format("~p ~n", [X])
    after 2000 ->
            timeout
    end,
    ok = ssl:send(Socket,  Message),    

    ssl:close(Socket),
    io:format("client closed~n").
```

The probelm I have is that listener 2 does not seem to be able to receive any messages. A sample run of the program looks like this:

First I start the server in shell 1.
Shell 1:

```
1> multiserver:start().
<0.34.0>
```

Then I call the client/1 three times from a different shell.
Shell 2:

```
2> multiserver:client("client").
{ssl,{sslsocket,new_ssl,<0.51.0>},<<"server">>} 
client closed
ok
3> multiserver:client("client").
{ssl,{sslsocket,new_ssl,<0.54.0>},<<"server">>} 
client closed
ok
4> multiserver:client("client").
{ssl,{sslsocket,new_ssl,<0.56.0>},<<"server">>} 
client closed
ok
```

This is the printouts to server shell.
Shell 1:

```
listener 1 accepted 
listener 1  sent
listener 1: {ssl,{sslsocket,new_ssl,<0.51.0>},<<"client">>} 
listener 2 accepted 
listener 2  sent
listener 1 accepted 
listener 1  sent
listener 1: {ssl,{sslsocket,new_ssl,<0.54.0>},<<"client">>} 
listener 2 timedout 
2>
```

I have spent some hours with this and I cant understand why it is not possible for listener 2 to receive any data. If I edit the code to use gen_tcp it works as expected. 
Is there something I am missing? 
Is it possible to do this with the current ssl module?

Comment: It seems that I'm running into the same issue... Have you got any information on it ?

Comment: No, the workaround is to run the clients in different shells. But I would like to know what is happening, why it is not possible with SSL while gen_tcp has no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the timeout is that in the second process uses the socket option **{active,false}**, i.e. the **receive** will never get any message.

The [erlang docs for the ssl module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html#transport_accept-1) states that the socket created by calling transport_accept/1 should inherit the options set for the listener socket. The first process inherits the options when it does transport_accept/3, but for some reason the second process doesn't. 
You can inspect the options with

```
ssl:getopts(ClientSocket,[mode, active])
```

I have no idea why this happens, but a workaround is to explicitly set the options on the newly accepted socket

```
ssl:setopts(ClientSocket, [{active,true}, {mode,binary}])
```